# Issue drawing line with two endpoints in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, drawing, uibezierpath, cashapelayer

I'm attempting to draw a line with a circular point centered on each end of it and add it as a layer to a view. I have the general concept down, but as you can see from the screenshot, the line is a little misaligned and I haven't been able to figure out why.

[image]

I'm also unsure why there's a line there to begin with (as you can see, I've commented out the two lines that were supposed to be used to draw the line, but the line is drawn anyway).

```
//Draw circle
UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithArcCenter:CGPointMake(100, 100) radius:10 startAngle:0 endAngle:DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(360) clockwise:TRUE];

//Add second circle
[path addArcWithCenter:CGPointMake(200.0, 200.0) radius:10 startAngle:0 endAngle:DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(360) clockwise:TRUE];
//[path addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(200.0, 200.0)];
//[path moveToPoint:CGPointMake(200.0, 200.0)];

[path closePath];
[[UIColor redColor] setStroke];
[[UIColor redColor] setFill];
[path stroke];
[path fill];

CAShapeLayer *shapeLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
shapeLayer.path = [path CGPath];
shapeLayer.strokeColor = [[UIColor redColor] CGColor];
shapeLayer.lineWidth = 4.0;
shapeLayer.fillColor = [[UIColor redColor] CGColor];

[self.view.layer addSublayer:shapeLayer];
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithArcCenter:CGPointMake(100, 100) radius:10 startAngle:0 endAngle:DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(360) clockwise:TRUE];     

//Add second circle
[path moveToPoint:CGPointMake(100.0, 100.0)];
[path addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(200, 200)];
[path moveToPoint:CGPointMake(200, 200)];

[path addArcWithCenter:CGPointMake(200, 200) radius:10 startAngle:0 endAngle:DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(360) clockwise:TRUE];
```